# visual studio -asp.net cor mvc nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

hello when i creat the new viwe in asp.net core mvc on  visual studio is alert to install package cod generator for to able the creat viwe

but
I'm getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urVbW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Za3K.png)

Comment: Looks like you're behind a firewall which is blocking access to the NuGet feed. You'll need to speak to your network administrators to get the restriction lifted.

Comment: It would be more helpful to future users if you would include error message as text instead of screen shot, because then it becomes searchable. Also the title of your question should relate to the error message. An edit to use fully grammatical sentences and avoid abbreviations would make your question more attractive for potential answerers.